How do solar cells really work?
When I read articles on the workings of photovoltaics, the explanation tends to revolve around the idea of PN-junctions, and how an electric field separates charges (electrons and holes). In a Quora answer Sjoerd Smit, who works with solar cells, questions that and gives a different explanation, based on a book by Peter Würfel.
https://www.quora.com/How-do-solar-cells-work
I‘m a bit confused now.
Does an electric field separate charges, or do selective contacts filter them out?

How the PN junction works, including its photo-sensitivity, has been known for a long time. I wouldn't bet on any new groundbreaking insights there...

The built-in field separates them. What is a ‘selective’ contact?

@JosBergervoet apparently its nothing groundbreaking, it‘s just another model to describe the same equations.

@JonCuster I posted the link so people can actually read his answer, but in summary he says that photons hitting a semiconductor excites electrons and elevates them to the conduction band leaving behind a hole in the valence band. Doped semiconductors act as selective contacts by only allowing either electrons or holes to pass. I don't want to misrepresent what he wrote, so i‘d recommend reading his answer.

That is incorrect. Turns out minority carriers can wander around in the bulk on either side of the junction before wandering back in and being separated.

You should give a short description of what the difference of this alternative explanation actually is as opposed to the conventional mechanism and why, if at all, it should lead to different results. You basically only give a reference we should study.

There are some small nitpicks with his presentation, but the general idea of what Sjoerd Smit said is correct. I don't think that the standard PN junction treatment with electric fields is in any disagreement with what he is saying. Often we are interested in PN junctions in general; a PV cell is a specific instance of a PN junction, so we tend to cover the topic together. The perpetual motion bit is just him not realising that people are not trying to assert what he is accidentally picking up.

@naturallyInconsistent So how exactly do they work? Is it the selectivity of the contacts as he puts it or the PN-junction that is responsible for the effect?
